# WPF - Streaming Video using HTTP/FTP

Tags: c#, wpf, video, stream, mp4

I'm going to steam mp4's from a server into my program. So far I've just used the `mediaElement1.Source=new Uri("HTTP ADDRESS");` `mediaElement1.Play();` it seems a bit too simple and it doesn't work sometimes(for some reason). I've also heard about `HttpListener` and other Listeners, But I'm not quite sure what's the difference(or what a Listener is) and what is the best way to stream quality videos from HTTP? Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific than "too simple" and "sometimes doesn't work ". We can't help if you don't add more details and ask very specific questions.

Comment: Also: stop repeating the same question. Add better details to the first one.

Comment: It takes a little so long to load videos using simple .Source and .Play, Can Listeners help me in any way solving this problem? What further information do you need to help me?

Comment: You you mean that it take too long? If so you need to find the bottleneck first (bandwidth, busy server, busy client, bad connection) before you start writing code. Why do you think a HttpListener will help?